# Is it possible to code a site similar to Amazon in scale in PHP?

Tags: php, scalability

Is PHP scalable enough to grow a project into something large?

(Yes, I am aware of Facebook, maybe there are other examples?)

Comment: Are **you** skillable enough to grow a project into something large?

Comment: Not me personally. Why do you ask? I can hire people.

Comment: Well you have to hire a software architect first. And it will be their concern. And I hope they'll have an answer without asking on SO

Comment: Well thanks for discouraging me to ask questions.

Comment: Hmmm.... Isn't Amazon itself written in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: yes.
There are quite a few large sites that run in PHP. Besides Facebook, Wikipedia and Flickr(I think) come to mind.

you can also see the list of [large sites built in drupal](http://buytaert.net/tag/drupal-sites), which is written in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Yep. I'd venture to guess that Amazon's scalability has more to do with the architecture, caching/write mechanisms, and heavy usage of EC2 and S3 then their chosen language.

Comment: Agreed, you'll spend a lot more time worrying about caching and databases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, PHP scalable enough to grow a project. Why facebook is not enough to proof?

Comment: Facebook's front facing parts may be in PHP, but the rest (their business logic, backend processes, etc) is not. They actually wanted to rewrite the interface in Python a few years ago, but decided it was too huge of a task...